Why does android app crash with SQLiteDiskIOException after update app?
After my app release, the following crash occurred.
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802 SQLITE_IOERR_FSTAT[1802]): , while compiling: PRAGMA cache_size
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1540)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:1075)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setCacheSizeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:536)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:416)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:228)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:758)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.tryAcquireNonPrimaryConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1355)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:983)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:619)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:916)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2278)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:2253)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.kt:156)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:490)
       at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.kt:75)
       at myapppackage.data.datasource.db.language.MultiLanguageStationNameDao_Impl$1.call(MultiLanguageStationNameDao_Impl.java:37)
       at myapppackage.data.datasource.db.language.MultiLanguageStationNameDao_Impl$1.call(MultiLanguageStationNameDao_Impl.java:34)
       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$createFlow$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:128)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

The Room library was used for the first time in the previous version, and the database has been updated in next version.
This is the Room database builder code.
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        AppDatabase::class.java, "new_database.db"
    ).createFromAsset("db/my_app_db.sqlite")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
}

The sqlite file is imported from assets, and new data has been added to this sqlite file.
However, the newly added data was not queried in the app, so I checked and found out that I needed to increase the version, so I added 1 to the version as shown below. (previously 1)
@Database(
    entities = [
        MultiLanguageStationNameEntity::class,
    ],
    version = 2
)

Repository
override fun getStationNames(): Flow<List<MultiLanguageStationNameRes>> {
    return multiLanguageStationNameDao.getStationNames()
        .map { entities ->
            entities.map {
                entity -> entity.asDomainModel()
           }
     }
}

Dao
@Dao
interface MultiLanguageStationNameDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MultiLanguageStationName")
    fun getStationNames(): Flow<List<MultiLanguageStationNameEntity>>
}

I wonder what caused the crash.
Is this because the app is updated while the DB is open?
I understand that fallbackToDestructiveMigration() will delete and recreate database.
Could this have an impact?

This might happen if the app still accesses or opens the database while the migration process is taking place.

So can this problem occur every time app updates?
I add catch to the Repository and it no longer crashes.
Is this the best option?

catching the exception prevents the crash by handling the error, but it is required to understand the root cause of the issue to address it effectively.
